# Impute constant and create missingness dummy

Tags: r, regression

A common strategy for dealing with missing predictors in a regression is to create a dummy variable and fill in a constant.

Eg:

```
lm(Y ~ X1 + replace(X2, is.na(X2), 0) + is.na(X2), df)
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Especially if I had X3, X4 etc that also had missing values, this would get very tedious and I would end up with the following ungainly formula:

```
Y ~ X1 + replace(X2, is.na(X2), 0) + is.na(X2) + 
         replace(X3, is.na(X3), 0) + is.na(X3) + 
         replace(X4, is.na(X4), 0) + is.na(X4)
```

It would also be nice to be able to impute the mean of the column instead of a zero.

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Y = c(3.83, 22.73, 13.85, 14.09, 20.55, 18.51, 
17.76, 9.42, 15.88, 27.81), X1 = 1:10, X2 = c(2L, NA, NA, 4L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 9L)), .Names = c("Y", "X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you want recommendations for imputation methods for your data, you should as at [stats.se] instead since this seems more like a statistics question rather than a programming question.

Comment: I'm happy with the imputation method, I want a more scalable / less tedious way of implementing the above.

Comment: What part is tedious? The replace? Do you just need to know how to perform the same operation on multiple columns in R?

Comment: The tedious part is manually creating two columns from each column, but only if it contains an NA, and doing so in the regression formula.

Comment: A better way t handle it is to modify the dataframe prior to plugging things into the data frame. You  could easily build a function and use apply to impute values and create imputation flags

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick that you can expect better answers on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But you may want to look into the [`MICE`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package.

Comment: MICE is for multiple imputation, which is a different methodology than using indicators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bit the bullet and went down this particular rabbit hole, posting to share my findings.

NA handling in R is done by `na.action` functions, which are provided to `model.frame` internally when you use a modeling function such as lm.

We can define our own, which replaces a column containing an NA with a matrix containing the original vector with the mean replacing the NA, and a dummy var indicating that happened. We can have the `data.frame` generic call the simpler implementation recursively:

```
na.dummy <- function(object, ...) {
  UseMethod("na.dummy", object)
}

na.dummy.numeric <- function(object, ..., m=mean(object, na.rm=TRUE)) {
  i <- is.na(object)

  structure(cbind(replace(object, i, m), `NA`=i*1), 
            class='na.dummy', m=m)
}

na.dummy.data.frame <- function(object, ...) {

  w <- vapply(object, anyNA, TRUE)
  cm <- rep(NA, length(object))


  for(j in which(w)) {
    object[[j]] <- na.dummy(object[[j]])
    cm[j] <- attr(object[[j]], 'm')


  }


  structure(object, 
            na.action=structure(cm, class='dummy'))
}
```

Surprisingly, this mostly works. However, when you try to `predict()` on new data, the system breaks. The below is a function which edits the model metadata to correctly set up the model frame for prediction:

```
fix_predvars <- function(object){


  pv <- attr(terms(object), "predvars")

  cm <- na.action(object)


  for(j in seq_along(cm)) {
    if(is.na(cm[j])) next

    newpv <- quote(na.dummy())
    newpv[[2]] <- pv[[j+1]]
    newpv[["m"]] <- cm[j]
    pv[[j+1]] <- newpv

  }
  attr(object$terms, 'predvars') <- pv

  object
}



makepredictcall.na.dummy <- function(var, call){
  if (as.character(call)[1L] != "na.dummy")
    return(call)
  call["m"] <- attr(var, "m")
  call
}

predict.na.dummy <- function(object, newx, ...)
{
  if(missing(newx))
    return(object)
  na.dummy(newx, m=attr(object, "m"))
}
```

This is an example of actually fitting a model, then using it to make a prediction when there is missing data:

```
> (m <- lm(Y~X1+X2, df, na.action = na.dummy))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2, data = df, na.action = na.dummy)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X1           X2         X2NA  
     0.2313       0.9715       1.9356       5.9521  

> m2 <- fix_predvars(m)
> predict(m2, newdata = data.frame(X1=2,X2=NA_real_))
       1 
17.80423
```